# Switching to https with wordpress : How to correctly setup 301 for google?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, seo

I am moving my WordPress website to https.

I am using the code below which works fine:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My only worry is SEO, how do I tell google my website has moved from http to https ?

I have seen people using `[R=301,L]` others `[L,R=301]` , which one is best ?
How should I edit my code ?

Comment: You're right in what you've seen. `R=301` will suffice. But, before you do, make sure everything is 100% working and it is doing what you want. You can start off by using `R=302` which works as a temporary direct for redirects. Once you're happy, switch it to 301.

Comment: I've done some research, I think I'm gonna stick to [R=301,L].